# python what should I use instead of while

Tags: python, while-loop

I was not advised to use while loop as it's not pythonic. I have done some research and I understand for most cases. I found it hard to think of an alternative way for my example if anyone could help me out.

```
time = getTime()
while time > dt:
    doSth(dt)
    time -= dt
```

How would you change this to a more pythonic way?

```
for i in range(time//dt):
    doSth(dt)
```

how about this?

Comment: Personally I would likely do it exactly as in your first example. If someone is telling you it's not pythonic, perhaps you should ask them why.

Comment: @BryanOakley I smiled, nodded, and said "ah" at the time :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through a range object like the following in a `for` loop instead, although there is nothing un-Pythonic about your `while` loop:

```
for time in range(getTime(), 0, -dt):
    doSth(dt) # or perhaps your mean to call doSth(time), since dt does not change
```

or, if your timestamp is a floating number:

```
for i in range(getTime() // dt):
    doSth(getTime() - i * dt)
```

Comment: Indeed. I've updated my answer with a solution that's compatible with a timestamp of a floating number.